# iOS Notification Service extension causes Program ended with exit code: 0

Tags: ios, rich-notifications

I'm having a trouble to use rich notification.
When I send a apns payload, my notification service extension print Program ended with exit code: 0 error message EXC_RESOURCE and show like normal notification.
The error message seems like attached picture.
[image]

my apns payload is

```
{
  "aps": {
    "sound": "default",
    "mutable-content": 1,
    "alert" : {
            "title" : "tt",
            "subtitle" : "st",
            "body" : "bd"
        },
    "badge": 2
  },
  "imgUrl": "http://someimagelink.jpeg"
}
```

I don't know why, but even it everything works fine if I try in a new project. Help me please.

Comment: did you ever found the problem?

Comment: @Andrespch nope.. I assume that It causes using several xconfig files with  framework link flags, but not sure..

Answer (score 0):

I guess you had imported some heavy library, which causes the issue because all extension is registered with iOS when app installs so there is the size limit on 20 MB (around) you can't exceed. If you exceed extension will be terminated by OS.

P.S Try to look service extension memory consumption in debug navigator. Hope it helps. I had faced same issue.